# Accessing jqXHR object properties from $.get request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function that looks like this:

```
function getURL(url) {
  return $.get(url);
}
```

Which im calling (somewhere else, specifically in a unit test) as such:

```
var url = getURL("/page/stuff")
    console.log(url);
```

So console.log(url) works, and returns statustext/status etc... like it should.

However, how can I access the properties of the jqXHR object. For instance `url.status` returns undefined.

Is this a loading issue? Whereas im logging before i've truly received the page...if so how come printing off just the url variable returns the object?

Comment: sounds like you're trying to read `url.status` before the ajax call completes; this would make url.status undefined.  You'll need to wait until the complete function fires, so shorthand `$.get` may not be the best option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I access the properties of the jqXHR object. For instance url.status returns undefined.

By accessing it after the request has completed:

```
var jqxhr = getURL("/page/stuff");

jqxhr.always(function (result) {
    console.log(jqxhr.status);
});
```

> Is this a loading issue? Whereas im logging before i've truly received the page...

Yes.

> if so how come printing off just the url variable returns the object?

Because `$.get()` returns an object that represents the request. But some of its properties are not populated until the request completes.

Comment: Where exactly does "result" come from?

Comment: Essentially, the jqXHR will hold onto the function that is passed into `.always()`  (or into `.then()`, or `.done()`, and when the request has finished, it will call that function and pass in the result. So that's where it comes from.

Comment: You can also access the jqxhr object before sending it with the attribute beforeSend

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.get()` is a `jQuery` promisse, so you have `xhr` options on the `Deferred` object.

I think you want this:

```
var _request = function( url ) {
    return $.get( url );
};

_request('https://httpbin.org/get').done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    console.info( jqXHR.status );
});
```

More information here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: Why is it we do jqXHR.status instead of data.status?

Comment: @msmith1114 There is no `data.status`. `data` is the data that was received.

Comment: @JLRishe im confused exactly at what "data" is then I guess. jqXHR is just the object properties, so data would be...whatever the page contents would be in this case I guess?

Comment: @msmith1114 Yes, it would be the contents of the response from the server.